# Windows Authentication works on IIS but not Kestrel / Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate (not in Chrome, sometimes in Edge, always in IE)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, iis, blazor, kestrel-http-server

I created a new Blazor (Server-side) application with Windows Authentication and run it using IIS Express. It will display a message of *"Hello Domain\User!"* from the following razor component (`...\BlazorApp1\BlazorApp1\Shared\LoginDisplay.razor`) on top right.

```
<AuthorizeView>
    Hello, @context.User.Identity.Name!
</AuthorizeView>
```

If running using Kestrel, the message is not shown. So I tried the following **[steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#kestrel)** to make it work in Kestrel.

1. Import NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate`
2. Add the following code in `ConfigureService()` in `Startup.cs`.

```
    services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();
```

3. Add the following code in `Configure()` in `Startup.cs`. They are added between `app.UseRouting();` and `app.UseEndpoints(...`;

```
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
```

It still doesn't show the Hello message. And I read *"Anonymous requests are allowed. Use ASP.NET Core Authorization to challenge anonymous requests for authentication."* in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#kestrel), so I did the following to disable anonymous requests.

In `_Host.cshtml`, added the following lines after `@namespace BlazorApp1.Pages`.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@attribute [Authorize]
```

However, the message is still not displayed? Does it mean the authorization is not working?

---

**Update:**

I updated the file `...\BlazorApp1\BlazorApp1\Shared\LoginDisplay.razor` to

```
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        Hello, @context.User.Identity.Name!
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        You are not authorized to view that page...
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

It shows "You are not authorized to view that page...". It seems the Windows Authentication is not working?

---

## Update2:

The following is mentioned in the doc.

> Windows environment configuration
>   The Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate component performs User Mode authentication. Service Principal Names (SPNs) must be added to the user account running the service, not the machine account. Execute `setspn -S HTTP/mysrevername.mydomain.com myuser` in an administrative command shell.

I tried to run the following command in Administrator powershell console on my personnel PC at home.

```
setspn -S HTTP/mypcname myusername
```

However, it got the error

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> setspn -S HTTP/desktop8930 nkucw
Ldap Error(0x51 -- Server Down): ldap_connect
Failed to retrieve DN for domain "" : 0x00000051
Warning: No valid targets specified, reverting to current domain.
FindDomainForAccount: Call to DsGetDcNameWithAccountW failed with return value 0x0000054B
Unable to locate account nkucw
```

Here is the output: (**It shows "Authorization was successful." a few times in the log**, but the last showes Authorization failed)

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\nkucw\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Users\nkucw**strong text**\source\repos\TestPS\BlazorApp1
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5001/
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.NegotiateHandler[12]
      AuthenticationScheme: Negotiate was challenged.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 135.0172ms 401
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5001/
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.NegotiateHandler[0]
      None
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.NegotiateHandler[1]
      Incomplete Negotiate handshake, sending an additional 401 Negotiate challenge.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 16.6473ms 401
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5001/
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.NegotiateHandler[0]
      None
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[1]
      Authorization was successful.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
      Executing endpoint '/_Host'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker[3]
      Route matched with {page = "/_Host"}. Executing page /_Host
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker[103]
      Executing an implicit handler method - ModelState is Valid
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker[104]
      Executed an implicit handler method, returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.PageResult.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[1]
      Authorization was successful.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker[4]
      Executed page /_Host in 206.51090000000002ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
      Executed endpoint '/_Host'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 270.6847ms 200 text/html; charset=utf-8
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5001/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5001/css/site.css
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.server.js
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[6]
      The file /css/site.css was not modified
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[6]
      The file /_framework/blazor.server.js was not modified
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[6]
      The file /css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css was not modified
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 26.105700000000002ms 304 text/css
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 21.6629ms 304 application/javascript
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 21.6629ms 304 text/css
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5001/css/open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[6]
      The file /css/open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css was not modified
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 7.1119ms 304 text/css
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST https://localhost:5001/_blazor/negotiate text/plain;charset=UTF-8 0
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
      Executing endpoint '/_blazor/negotiate'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
      Executed endpoint '/_blazor/negotiate'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 22.780900000000003ms 200 application/json
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5001/css/open-iconic/font/fonts/open-iconic.woff
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[6]
      The file /css/open-iconic/font/fonts/open-iconic.woff was not modified
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5001/_blazor?id=ase9fodeUXavBCDTwk1Suw
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 7.676900000000001ms 304 application/font-woff
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
      Executing endpoint '/_blazor'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed.
```

---

## Update3:

Found out it works in Edge, but not in Chrome. Is it a bug of the server-side Blazor?

## Update4:

Even with Edge, keeping refreshing the page shows that it may not get the authentication sometimes.

Comment: Well, you took all the steps, it looks like there might be a problem with the docs here. Do note that that page talks about asp.net in general, not Blazor. It still should have worked but Blazor evolves faster.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58880133/60761), it might be relevant: "Kestrel brings it's own certificate management"

Comment: "Kestrel brings it's own certificate management" solves the problem of the brower https connection problem. I did encounter the problem when I was trying http.sys. However, following the steps above, the browser can see the page. It seems the Windows Authentication is not working.

Comment: I experimented a little further, and it _does_ work with Edge and Chrome, just not FireFox... . That does point to a certifcate issue.

Comment: It does not work flawless, you dou need to put the [Authorize] in _Host and then it screws up the first page load, but still, I can see my name.

Comment: It's also not specific to Blazor, I see the same results with a simple MVC app.

Comment: Interesting. I still got `NotAuthorized`.  Did you follow exactly the steps in the question?

Comment: Yes, same steps. But today I can't get it to work in Chrome anymore, wonder what that is. So it only works in Edge now.

Answer (score 9):

I found your question while tackling a similar [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/17527). I think I know the answer to your problem though - you can use a simple middleware which will challenge the authentication and display the login.

1. Add this in your Configure method:

```
app.UseMiddleware<ValidateAuthentication>();
```

2. Here is the middleware itself:

```
internal class ValidateAuthentication : IMiddleware
{
  public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
  {
    if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        await next(context);
    else
        await context.ChallengeAsync();
  }
}
```

3. And in ConfigureServices :

```
 services.AddSingleton<ValidateAuthentication>();
```

You should not need a constructor.

Comment: I got the error of `System.InvalidOperationException: 'A suitable constructor for type 'BlazorApp3.ValidateAuthentication' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.'`. I tried to add `services.AddScoped<ValidateAuthentication>();` too.

Comment: I tried with .NET Core 3.1 Preview 3. Maybe it is different for other versions.

Comment: This works perfectly (AspCore 3.0, in Chrome). I'll add the service reg.

Comment: What could matter (a lot) is the place _where_ you insert this middleware into the pipeline.

Comment: This should be in the doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#kestrel

Comment: It works locally now. However, trying to access the page remotely will get error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59204346/aspnetcore-authentication-negotiate-negotiatehandler-an-anonymous-request-was-r

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I guess you may enable the IE user authentication automatic logon with current username and password setting, since the chrome also use this setting to avoid showing the popup for the windows auth.

I suggest you could try to follow below steps to modify the setting and try again.

1.Open the IE and find the internet options.

[image]

2.Modify the user authentication mode to **promot for username and password**

[image]

3.Close the ie and chrome and try again.

Comment: My company computer disabled these settings. BTW, even it works for Edge, it stops working from time to time when keeping refreshing the page.

Comment: I suggest you could try to use fiddler to capture the details request when you reproduce your issue on the edge.