# MVC Core Windows Authentication not working

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, windows-authentication

I'm trying to set up an MVC Core Web App with Windows Authentication in Visual Studio 2022 but I can't get it to work.

I create a new project and select the Windows Authentication option. I immediately try to run the app but I get a blank page.

For troubleshooting I then added the following else clause so I can see what the problem is on my development machine.

```
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}
else
{
    // Development Environment
    app.UseStatusCodePages();
}
```

and I can then see that I have a '401 Unauthorised' status code. And then if I add [AllowAnonymous] to my Index action I can finally see the home page but my windows username is not displayed. I would expect to see 'Hello username' displayed in the top right but I don't seem to be authenticated, let alone authorized.

Apart from the two troubleshooting steps above, this is a brand new project straight out of the box but I've pasted my Program.cs below for reference.

What do I need to do to get Windows Authentication to work?

Thanks

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

else
{
    // Development Environment
    app.UseStatusCodePages();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow my steps to fix the issue.

1. Enable IIS features in your develop machine, this just want to enable Windows authentication on Windows.

   [image]

   **Tips:** Please expand all the fields and tick them, then click Apply.

   [image]
2. Delete the `.vs` folder inside your project, this steps just want to reset the `applicationhost.config`.
3. The latest step, we need to double check the settings file in project.

   [image]

Then the issue should be fixed now.

Comment: Thanks Jason.  This didn't exactly fix my problem but it did point me in the right direction.  I was using the Kestrel  web server as that's the default, rather than IIS.  When I selected IIS instead, everything worked as expected.  I wonder if it's possible to configure Kestrel to use Windows Authentication but I don't actually need to do that so maybe that's a question for another thread.  Thanks again - problem solved.

Comment: @lonelyoutpost Just now I test in my local and use Kestrel, it works well and I don't know why. If you are intresting about this issue, you can check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53842990/windows-authentication-for-kestrel-hosted-in-windows-service).

Comment: It may be something to do with the fact that I was in a domain environment, at work.  When I try from home, with Kestrel, it does work.  Anyway, thanks for the link.  I'll check it out.  Thanks for coming back to me.

Comment: I discovered that this issue is unique to Firefox.  When I run a Windows Authentication app in Chrome, with Kestrel, it works fine!

Comment: I've found the solution to this [thanks to Rich Strahl](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Nov/14/FireFox-Windows-Security-and-Kestrel-on-ASPNET-Core)