# Problem with authentication in ASP.NET Core on mac

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-identity

I have an ASP.NET Core 6.0 web application that uses `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` in order to authenticate users.

Everything is ok when I run application on Windows and IIS and SigIn section works properly, but when I run on Mac with Kestrel, it returns to the login page without authentication.

Is the problem related to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` package that just works on Windows?

Comment: When you run on Mac/Linux, then paths (upper/lowecase) might be a source of trouble.  What error do you get? what does the logs say?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows Authentication for Kestrel hosted in Windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53842990/windows-authentication-for-kestrel-hosted-in-windows-service)